# How to split a timestamp from 15 Minutes into 3 parts like every 5 minutes via SQL

Tags: sql, split, timestamp

I have a database which is really easy to handle normally. This dataset has a start_time, end_time, modellnumber, roomnumber.
So I made a SQL which shows me a table how long each modell was in a room.
But what I need is a table which shows me every 5 Minutes a new column, whether the modell was in this room. For better understanding :

First SQL:
modell room  start_time             end_time

- 217      5    31.10.2022 10:05:00   31.10.2022 10:17:00

Second SQL:
modell room  duration_time

- 217     5     00:12:00

Needed SQL:
modell  room  time

- 217      5    31.10.2022 10:05:00
- 217      5    31.10.2022 10:10:00
- 217      5    31.10.2022.10:15:00

I wrote some different functions with trunc but nothing of them worked. Maybe someone have an idea with the examples I wrote down how to get the result I want.
Please be kind, I am starting on this..

So this is my Second SQL for getting the duration time:

select(to_timestamp(end_time) - to_timestamp(start_time)) as duration_time, modell, room
from objects

Comment: which rdbms are you using? can you provide a sample table?

Comment: The rdbms is Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that you can mold to fit your needs. Let me know if you have any other questions.

```
with cal (col1, st, et) as 
(
               select col1, start_time as st, end_time as et  from t
    union all  select col1, st + interval '5' minute, et from cal where st <= et-interval '5' minute
)

select   *
from     cal 
order by col1, st
```

| COL1 | ST | ET |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 31-OCT-22 10.05.00.000000000 | 31-OCT-22 10.17.00.000000 |
| 1 | 31-OCT-22 10.10.00.000000000 | 31-OCT-22 10.17.00.000000 |
| 1 | 31-OCT-22 10.15.00.000000000 | 31-OCT-22 10.17.00.000000 |
| 2 | 31-OCT-22 10.17.00.000000000 | 31-OCT-22 10.30.00.000000 |
| 2 | 31-OCT-22 10.22.00.000000000 | 31-OCT-22 10.30.00.000000 |
| 2 | 31-OCT-22 10.27.00.000000000 | 31-OCT-22 10.30.00.000000 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y6nb-X4v)

Comment: Oh thank you so much for this idea :)  !  with the interval I think it is a good idea. But it should stop after 10:15 because then it change the room. 
So we ned maybe a border that it only should make a new column if the modell is in the room. Because of this I made the SQL with duration time.

Comment: I added another time to the info to show you how it would look. it does stop